# ajax send form request to the same page to run SQL/PHP queries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#message").hide();
$("#please_wait_box").hide();
$("#addnotification").submit(function(e){
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#please_wait_box").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#addnotification").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "menu.php?addnotification=yes",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(res){
            $("#please_wait_box").hide();
            $("#message").html(res);
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.overlay').fadeOut();
            if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
            {
                window.location.href = res.substr(8);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

i am trying to run this ajax code to POST data to menu.php page from a submitted form

on menu.php i have

```
if($_GET["addnotification"] == 'yes') {
    //do stuff here
    echo 'form submitted';
}
```

but i cannot see the text `form submitted`

**UPDATE**

i have changed to this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#message").hide();
$("#please_wait_box").hide();
$("#addnotification").submit(function(e){
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#please_wait_box").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#addnotification").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addnotification.php",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(res){
            $("#please_wait_box").hide();
            $("#message").html(res);
            $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
            {
                window.location.href = res.substr(8);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

and put the SQL queries on a different page, but now the `please_wait_box` shows and does not hide, the queries are not running at all

Comment: your GET key should be addnotification?

Comment: try alert(res); do you get form submitted text in alert box?

Answer (score 1):

In your url you've got no blank, but in your php document there is a blank.

```
menu.php?addnotification=yes
```

vs

```
$_GET["add notification"]
```

Comment: made a mistake when typing :)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST request and then reading the $_GET response, try changing the

```
type: "POST",
```

for

```
type: "GET",
```

in your ajax call.

and also read addnotification and not add notification (probably a typo)

Comment: OP is sending addnotification as GET paramater so it is not required to change POST to GET.

Answer (score 0):

Check your this part of code:

```
if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
{
  window.location.href = res.substr(8);
}
```

You are searching for success in res whereas i think your res will be a string "form submitted". You can try calling alert(res); or console.log(res) to see what is being returned in your response.

Additional debugging process:
change your code for ajax to below:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addnotification.php",
    cache: false,
    data: dataString
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
  $("#please_wait_box").hide();
  $("#message").html(msg);
  $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
  if(msg.indexOf("success")!=-1)
  {
    window.location.href = msg.substr(8);
  }
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: What do you get when you do alert(res);?

Comment: Try edited code for debugging your code. Make sure your php file addnotification.php is accessible. you can use developer tools in chrome to see what actually is being sent in request.